# calling database date functions in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I'm using having function in code igniter active record but it produces wrong results.

```
$this->db->having('y', 'year('.$date.')');
```

produces :

```
`y` =  'year(2014-2-1)'
```

and this:

```
$this->db->having('y', 'year('.$date.')',true);
```

is only escaping the name of the column so it produces:

```
 y = year('2014-2-1')
```

but  i want to produce this:

```
`y` = year('2014-2-1')
```

or this

```
 `y` = year(2014-2-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [***active record***](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) documentation you can do so,pass third parameter as FALSE  so column will be protected for adding back-ticks and you can add back-ticks  manually

```
$this->db->having("`y` = YEAR('".$date."')",null,FALSE);
```